# Django url doesn't see context variable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have Profile view in which I set context variable - user nick:

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile/templates/profile.html'
    redirect_field_name = ''

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    profile_id = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id)
    context['user_nick'] = Blogger.objects.get(profile_id=profile_id).nick
    return context
```

And url for it:

```
path('bloggers/<slug:nick>/videos', bloggers_views.BloggerVideos.as_view(), name='blogger_videos'),
```

Also I'm passing nick in my navbvar:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% include 'navbar/templates/navbar.html' with nick=user_nick %}
{% endif %}
```

Referencing to it like:

```
<li><a href= {% url 'bloggers' %}><span>Bloggers {{ nick }}</span></a></li>
<li><a href= {% url 'blogger_videos' nick %}>Blogger's videos</a></li>
```

It's weird that in first case Django renders nick correctly, but in second it crashes with following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /bloggers/Gardiner/videos
Reverse for 'blogger_videos' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) 
tried: ['bloggers\\/(?P<nick>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/videos$']
```

It doesn't see nick at all:

```
candidate_subs {'nick': ''}
```

What will be the possible solution?

Comment: It looks like the `Blogger` has no nick. Are you sure that it has a nickname? Can you `print(..)` the content?

Comment: Instead of `with nick=user_nick`, maybe you should do `with nick=user.nick`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, it has.

Comment: @ozgur nope, user_nick is rendered ok in profile page

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the variable as `user_nick`, not `nick`. Also, you should refer to it in the tag by keyword argument. And thirdly, you should put the whole URL in quotes in the HTML.

```
<a href="{% url 'blogger_videos' nick=user_nick %}">
```

Comment: Does the code in the question reflect your actual indentation? If so the `get_context_data` will never be called, it needs to be indented inside the ProfileView class.

Comment: Omg, sorry. In my code it's indented exactly inside the ProfileView class